# Random Pick 2 Int as an option

Tags: c#, random, int

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1000);
    int RandomTolerance = 5 || 10;
    lblRandomValue.Text = randomNumber + "000" + "O" + RandomTolerance;
}
```

I do not understand how to allow the `RandomTolerance` to choose between 5 and 10 only as an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int RandomTolerance=random.Next(0,2)<1?5:10;
```

As a side note, reseeding your random number generator over and over is usually a bad idea. You should read up on how random number generators work.

Comment: Or grab Jon Skeet's class and call [`ThreadLocalRandom.Next(0,2)`](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx) .  Use the version in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) if your version of .Net is too old for that one.

Comment: @Blindly im currently facing another problem. I'm still beginner at CSharp :/ could u help me some bit ? :D

Comment: @Kade: I suggest you post a new question.  Note: If your question is, "why does `btnStart_Click` end up with the same `randomNumber` if I click it twice in rapid succession?", the answer is, "reseeding your random number generator over and over is usually a bad idea."

Answer (score 2):

```
int RandomTolerance = random.Next(1,3) * 5;
```

Disclaimer: @Blindy, this sounded better :)